# ∃(X) ∙ ∀(Y) ∙ p(X) ⇒ p(Y) Provide a true and false Structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$\exists(X)$ $\bullet$ $\forall$(Y) $\bullet$ p(X)  $\Rightarrow$ p(Y)

I am struggling to give to a structure for the following formula, one such that the truth value of the formula is T and one such that is it F.

I am reading the formula as follows

*There exists some X that implies all Y*

and that the predicate is the same..so p could be isBlue for example

*There is exists some X which is blue that implies all Y is blue*

Comment: [The formula $\exists x\forall y(p(x)\to p(y))$ is valid.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%83x%E2%88%80y(p(x)%E2%86%92p(y)))

Comment: For example, if $x$ is a yellow object then the claim "$x$ is blue implies $y$ is blue" is true.  Not very interesting, but true.

Answer (score 0):

> There is exists some X which is blue that implies all Y is blue

More correctly: "There is something which, *if* it is blue, *then* everything is blue."

The existential statement does not guarantee that it has a witness that *is blue*.  Only that everything will be blue *if* that witness is.

I remind you of two facts:

- (1) Implications are valued true when the consequent is true *or* the antecedent is false.
- (2) Existential statements are *vacuously false* for empty domains.

This will give you three structures to examine.